# ¿Cómo pasar la cadena de texto de un Jtextfield a una variable double (Herencia)?

Tags: java, string, herencia, double

Lo que ocurre es que tengo que hacer una nómina, donde se calcule el salario de los trabajadores, pero cada clase tiene herencia. Por ejemplo la clase trabajador base es hereditaria de trabajador, pero la mayoría de las variables está en trabajador, como tipo `protected`, así:

```
  protected double paybyhour;
```

Cuando quiero almacenar la cantidad en esta variable para hacer las operaciones matemáticas desde un `textField` en una interfaz, me rebota este error;

> *Double cannot be converted to string*

aquí el código:

```
private void txtpaybyhourKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    txtname.setText(Double.parseDouble(obj.getPaybyhour()));

}
```

El método para llamar y obtener o escribir en esta variable es publico, pero la variable en sí es `protected`.

Comment: Para convertir un double a un string necesitas el metodo String.valueof() ya que Double.parseDouble() convierte un String a un dato de tipo double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregando con el compañero **FrEqDe** al agregar **obj.getPaybyhour()+""** Lo que estas haciendo es concatenar el valor **obj.getPaybyhour()** (tipo de dato Double) a una cadena vacía **""**, por lo que juntos ya forman una cadena en sí (String).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el método `setText()` recibe un String y tú intentas pasar un double, basta cómo que hagas el siguiente cambio.

```
private void txtpaybyhourKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    txtname.setText(obj.getPaybyhour()+"");

}
```